# How to highlight multiple cells based on value on click in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

**Context**

The Excel file is made up of 2 parts.

1. A regular data set (Picture included below)
2. 2D-representation of multiple machine modules and their corresponding cable trenches.

**The Task**

I'd like to **highlight the corresponding cells** in the 2D-representations **when I click on an ID in the data set**.

This mockup-image shows the desired effect.
[image: Image of multiple selected fields with duplicates that should be filled]
As seen in the image, there are multiple cells with duplicate values in the 2D-represenatation that needs highlighting

How would one go about doing something like this?

Comment: You will have to use VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex suggested, the Worksheet_SelectionChange Event was a the way to go.
It is now working as intended.

[image: Working as intended]

Here's what I wrote.

```
\\Constructor
\\ResetColors
\\MakeTrenchYellow subroutines here.

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And 3 - Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Constructor
        ResetColors

        Dim SelectedRowTextjoin As String
        SelectedRowTextjoin = Target.Offset(0, 6).Value

        Dim CurrentResult As Variant
        CurrentResult = Split(SelectedRowTextjoin, ", ")

        Dim AmountOfElements As Integer
        For Each Item In CurrentResult
            AmountOfElements = AmountOfElements + 1
        Next

        For i = 1 To AmountOfElements
            MakeTrenchYellow (CurrentResult(i - 1))
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use VBA as Jerry says. I would look at the [Worksheet_SelectionChange Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange)
To trigger the highlighting and use a for-loop to go trough the columns to check if the corresponding cell needs to be highlighted.